# Should we remove the "parenting" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

As of right now, [we have 10 questions tagged "parenting"](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parenting?sort=newest&pagesize=50). (Nine; I just edited one.)

Given that our entire site is about parenting, this tag makes no sense at all and should be removed -- if it's allowed to stay, then *every* question should be tagged "parenting" and that would clearly be meaningless.

Is there any reason to keep this tag, or can we remove it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I say it absolutely should go.  It's meaningless noise, like including a "Programming" tag on StackOverflow.com, or a "Ubuntu" tag on askubuntu.com.

However, this does raise the issue of how we should retag a couple of the questions that currently have the [parenting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parenting) tag.

[This one](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/4127/what-are-some-ways-to-measure-parental-success-in-america) and [this one](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/4078/what-to-do-when-parents-disagree-regarding-their-parenting) both have that as the sole tag.

The first one is closed as a dup of [this question](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/4003/how-do-you-evaluate-yourself-as-a-parent), which uses [learning](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning), but I'm not sure that's the best tag for either version.

Perhaps a more specific [parents](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parents) tag would be appropriate for these, to indicate that the focus of the question is the parent?  The [communication](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/communication) might be a good addition to the [second question](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/4078/what-to-do-when-parents-disagree-regarding-their-parenting).

[This question](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/4977/how-do-you-deal-with-when-youve-had-a-parenting-fail) has the [parenting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parenting) and the vague and ambiguous [action](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/action).

For this, I suggest that we replace both with [behavior](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behavior) and [communication](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/communication).

Comment: I haven't compared each question vs. your suggestions but I trust your call. A "parents" tag would make sense!

Comment: A quick look at each suggests @Beofett's suggestions work - for me at least.

Comment: I'm retagging the questions now, and making use of a new "parents" tag, and also the "behavior" tag for some of the questions.