# Do we need a "Parents" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Similar to our question on "[Do we need a 'Parenting' tag?](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/397/should-we-remove-the-parenting-tag)", do we need [parents](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parents)?

Is this tag redundant, or does it serve a legitimate purpose?  If so, what is it?

We don't seem to be using it that consistently: sometimes it is about children asking about how they should discuss something with their parents; other times, it is used to identify that the question relates to the parents; still others use it to indicate the parents of the parents.

If we want to continue using this tag, we should clarify what it is for, and how we should use it.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes.**

I think we should keep the tag but clarify its use. I suggest this definition:

> The *parents* tag covers questions *about the parents* but they must still be related to *parenting.*

This other meta question mentions some example questions:  [Would we accept questions *about* parents?](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226/would-we-accept-questions-about-parents)
All questions are on-topic, but not all of them require the [parents](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parents) tag.

Proper use:

- How should parents react on their kids being gay?
- How should parents resolve their parenting disagreements?
- How should kids resolve disagreements with their parents?
- I'm am embarrassed by my mother's good-bye kisses around my friends, what should I do?
- I've become sexually active, should I tell my parents?

Don't use [parents](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parents) when the focus isn't on the parents:

- How should parents do (parenting activity X)?
- What stroller features are essential for (purpose X)?
- A friend at school started smoking and tried to pressure me into smoking too. Should I "snitch" him out to his parents?